# Foreign Keys in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Im using a SQLite DB when creating my DB using c# code and Visual studio or SQLite Expert personal everything is working fine. When trying to add data to the db using SQLite Expert personal my Foreign Key Constraints are working as expected, but when i try to insert data using c# I can add Data violating a Foreign Key Constraint. Can anybody tell me why?

heres my c# code:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO tblLicenseInfo 
(UserID, MachineID, ExpirationDate, DateOfChange, LicenseKey)
 VALUES (2, 1, '2014-04-03 12:15:00', '2014-04-03 12:15:00', '123123erer')", SqLite);
```

theres no entry in `tblUser` with `UserID = 2` and no entry with `MachineID = 1`. When I try the same sql statement in Expert Personal it shows an error msg, but in Visual studio no exception is thrown - the data is just insert into my table (I can see the entry when I open the DB with Expert Personal).

thank you very much.

EDIT:

I now added some code, so it looks like this:

```
SQLiteCommand foo = new SQLiteCommand("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;", SqLite);
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO tblLicenseInfo 
(UserID, MachineID, ExpirationDate, DateOfChange, LicenseKey)
VALUES (2, 1, '2014-04-03 12:15:00', '2014-04-03 12:15:00', '123123erer')", SqLite);

SqLite.Open();
foo.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqLite.Close();
```

Is this still wrong? I can still insert the data into my DB.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key constraints were added as an optional feature to SQLite so you need to enable them.

When you first open the connection execute the SQL command:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

which does what it appears to.